# Ignore punctuation symbol while giving tokens in spacy

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I am new to using `SpaCy`. Can we tell spacy API to ignore symbols while giving tokens?

Example:

For the sentence `Hi, Welcome to StackOverflow.` The tokens are

```
Hi
,
Welcome
to
StackOverflow
.
```

I want spacy to give tokens only for words which have whitespace. For the above example, the tokens should be

```
Hi,
Welcome
to
StackOverflow.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
txt = "Hi, Welcome to StackOverflow."
doc = nlp(txt)
tokens = [tok.text for tok in doc if not tok.is_punct]
print(tokens)
['Hi', 'Welcome', 'to', 'StackOverflow']
```

You may wish to define your own list of punctuation:

```
punctuation = [".",",","!"]
tokens = [tok.text for tok in doc if tok.text not in punctuation]
print(tokens)
['Hi', 'Welcome', 'to', 'StackOverflow']
```

or use a readily available one from `string` package:

```
from string import punctuation
print(punctuation)
doc_punct = nlp(" ".join([punctuation]))
tokens = [tok.text for tok in doc if tok.text not in punctuation]
print(tokens)
!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~
['Hi', 'Welcome', 'to', 'StackOverflow']
```

Comment: I want the list to be ['Hi,', 'Welcome', 'to', 'StackOverflow.']. Punctuations should be included in the word.